# How do I write an rspec test for this

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am having a hard time creating a test for my draw_three_by_three method...here is my code...below that I will list my test code that doesn't work...can you help me figure this out?

```
class GameIO
  attr_reader :stdin, :stdout
  def initialize(stdin = $stdin, stdout = $stdout)
    @stdin  = stdin
    @stdout = stdout
  end

  def draw_three_by_three(board)
    out_board = "\n"
    out_board << " #{board.grid[0]} | #{board.grid[1]} | #{board.grid[2]}\n"
    out_board << "-----------\n"
    out_board << " #{board.grid[3]} | #{board.grid[4]} | #{board.grid[5]}\n"
    out_board << "-----------\n"
    out_board << " #{board.grid[6]} | #{board.grid[7]} | #{board.grid[8]} \n"
    output out_board
  end

  def output(msg)
    stdout.puts msg
  end
end
```

---

Here is my rspec code that is wrong...How do I write an rspec test for this?

```
require 'game_io'
require 'board'

describe 'game_io' do
  before(:each) do
    @gameio = GameIO.new
    @board  = Board.new

  end

  context 'draw_three_by_three_board' do
    it 'should display the board on standard output' do
      @gameio.draw_three_by_three(@board).should == <<-EOF.gsub(/^ {6}/, '')

       + | + | +
      -----------
       + | + | +
      -----------
       + | + | + 
      EOF
    end
  end
end
```

---

and this is the rspec error I'm getting....

$ rspec spec/game_io_spec.rb

```
 + | + | +
-----------
 + | + | +
-----------
 + | + | +

F
```

Failures:

```
1) game_io draw_three_by_three_board should display the board on standard output
   Failure/Error: EOF
     expected: "\n + | + | +\n-----------\n + | + | +\n-----------\n + | + | + \n"
          got: nil (using ==)
   # ./spec/game_io_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Finished in 0.00074 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Comment: The `output` method doesn't return anything - it simply sends it to stdout via `puts`.

Comment: Yeah test it on console. `puts` prints to shell and returns `nil`.

Comment: I would prefer `draw_three_by_three ` just generate a string, but not output it into stdout, so for your test, you can just test this method.

Comment: Agree with Mike Li. Attempting to test your code has revealed a flaw, you have one method that does two things and you want to test the first by itself.

Answer (score 0):

For hints on how to test for output, if it is truly necessary, look at the built in testing framework in Ruby called Minitest.  It has the assertion/spec `assert_output` / `must_output` that makes this kind of testing easy.

```
##
 # Fails if stdout or stderr do not output the expected results.
 # Pass in nil if you don't care about that streams output. Pass in
 # "" if you require it to be silent. Pass in a regexp if you want
 # to pattern match.
 #
 # NOTE: this uses #capture_io, not #capture_subprocess_io.
 #
 # See also: #assert_silent

 def assert_output stdout = nil, stderr = nil
   out, err = capture_io do
     yield
   end

   err_msg = Regexp === stderr ? :assert_match : :assert_equal if stderr
   out_msg = Regexp === stdout ? :assert_match : :assert_equal if stdout

   y = send err_msg, stderr, err, "In stderr" if err_msg
   x = send out_msg, stdout, out, "In stdout" if out_msg

   (!stdout || x) && (!stderr || y)
 end
```